# How to capture jenkins build cause? triggered by GitLab

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, hudson, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkins file(groovy syntax), manual build action(if any) cause is grabbed using `hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause` in  `currentBuild.getBuildCauses('hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause')`

---

`hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger.SCMTriggerCause` looks deprecated in Jenkins CI [code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/triggers/SCMTrigger.java#L123).

```
    @Deprecated
    public SCMTrigger(String scmpoll_spec, boolean ignorePostCommitHooks) throws ANTLRException {
        super(scmpoll_spec);
        this.ignorePostCommitHooks = ignorePostCommitHooks;
    }
```

---

On push event or merge event from GitLab, How do Jenkinsfile read the build cause?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to execute a stage on a Gitlab trigger:

```
stage('stage') {
    when {
        triggeredBy "GitLabWebHookCause"
    }
}
```

To get the data of the Gitlab cause you have the following syntax:

```
currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.cause.GitLabWebHookCause).getData()
```

Example: get last commit

```
commit = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.cause.GitLabWebHookCause).getData().getLastCommit()
```

Documentation of the GitlabWebHookCause:
https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/gitlab-plugin/com/dabsquared/gitlabjenkins/cause/GitLabWebHookCause.html